# SSIS Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, ado.net, ssis-2012

From SSIS data tools we have a connection to mysql database with ADO.NET source component, with the following connection sting: server=123.123.123.123;user id=username;database=databasename;connectiontimeout=9000;

RetainSameConnection:False
SupportsDTCTransations: True

The problem is that the schedules jobs and the manual executed jobs are failing randomly (50%-50% ) with the following message
Error: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection  with the following error message: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.".

Comment: Is this MySQL host a VM? Are there running backups on MySQL server while trying to connect? high load of RAM while trying to connect? are being reported the same issues while connecting to other servers?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta Thanks for your comment. you can see the problem below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the admins added a second connection with a load balancer. For the 1st connection (old) the IP was approved but the 2nd connection (new) the IP was not approved so, every time it was switching to the new connection thru the load balancer the connection was failing.